# Как получить адрес объекта location

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram

Получаю следующие значения а необходимо полный адрес местонахождения.

**Как получить адрес в нормальном виде?** Возможно ли это?

[image: Получаю следующие значения а необходимо полный адрес местонахождения]

---

Получаю следующие значения а необходимо полный адрес местонахождения

Comment: приведите пример Вашего кода. Вы можете использовать `Геокодер`

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать модуль geopy:

```
pip install geopy
```

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="specify_your_app_name_here")
location = geolocator.reverse("52.509669, 13.376294")
```

Объект location будет содержать всю необходимую информацию – адрес и т.д.